# Pandas Dataframe returning unsupported type error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an error when I call

```
DataFrame(correlation_mat)

<repr(<pandas.core.frame.DataFrame at 0xa36c02c>) failed: TypeError: unsupported operand      type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'>
```

I'm not sure why because

```
correlation_mat.dtype
```

returns

```
dtype('float64')
```

I am not sure how to fix this.

Comment: Can you show us what `correlation_mat` looks like? Based on the message, I would guess you are doing something that subtracts strings and ints. And the operative word here is `guess`.

Comment: Also, it looks like the repr is failing, not the df creation. Perhaps pandas is taking the first row as column names? Regardless, try `df = DataFrame(correlation_mat)` and inspect that, I'm guessing the ctor will succeed.